# SetClientCredential visible in vs.net 2005 but not 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-services, authentication, wse

I add a web reference to my wse 3.0 service in Visual Studio 2005 and my intellisense shows the name of my service like `MyServiceWse` (it adds the WSE extension to the name).

I also have access to `SetClientCredentials()` where I pass in my `UsernameToken`, everything works fine.

In Visual Studio 2008 I don't have the proxy class with `MyServiceWse`, I have `MyService` only, so I don't have access to `SetClientCredentials()` etc.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last I read, WSE support is not directly available in VS 2008. There are some manual techniques in the link below which you can try out. I am also waiting for a better solution.

[WSE 3.0 and Visual Studio 2008?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/84299cff-5af6-4cef-8b6e-a8251df3d496/)

Answer (score -1):

WCF would be a better solution than WSE. WSE is obsolete, and has been replaced by WCF.